# Why is this binomial equation not an identity between polynomials?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

In the book [Concrete Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics), the following identity appears:
$$(r-k){r\choose k} = r {r-1\choose k}$$
It is followed by a proof that it holds for all real r. This proof makes use of the property that

> both sides of [the identity] are polynomials in r of degree k+1.

So far so good. However, the passage goes on by claiming that the following identity cannot be extended to real values for r this way, because it is not and identity between polynomials.
$${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$$

How can the factors (r-k) and r make the first identity polynomial when the second is not; am I missing some other difference that is critical?

Comment: I suppose what is meant in the first case is polynomials in $r$. Then obviously, the second expression $n \choose {n-k}$ is not a polynomial in $n$. It is a rational function.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, I see, the second identity being between two rational functions makes sense. But wouldn't the first one be between two rational functions then as well?

Comment: @RobertHönig No, because you can write $\binom{r}{k} = \frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-(k+1))}{k!}$, which is a polynomial in $r$ with rational coefficients.

Comment: I'm confused; couldn't I use the same argument for the second identity then as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recall the definition (5.1) of binomial coefficients stated in chapter 5 *[Binomial coefficients](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and integer values $p$

\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{p}=
\begin{cases}
  \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-p+1)}{p!}&p\geq 0\\
  0&p<0
\end{cases}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> The identity $(r-k)\binom{r}{k}=r\binom{r-1}{k}$ has a representation according to (1) as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{k!}(r-k)r(r-1)\cdots(r-k+1)=\frac{1}{k!}r(r-1)(r-2)\cdots(r-k)
> \end{align*}
>   Both sides coincide and are polynomials in $r$ of degree $k+1$.  On the other hand the identity $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ has a representation according to (1) as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{k!}n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-(n-k)+1)}{(\color{blue}{n}-k)(\color{blue}{n}-k-1)\cdots (\color{blue}{n}-k-(n-k)+1)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

In (2) we see the right hand side is a rational function with numerator and denominator being polynomials in $n$ of degree $n-k$.

Since the argument stated in the book is valid for polynomials only but not for rational functions in general, it cannot be applied to (2).

Comment: Aah, I see. So we can use the polynomial argument for the first equation because we can remove the $1/k$ from both sides, and the remaining identity will then hold for all real $r$, correct?

Comment: @RobertHönig: We even don't  need  to remove $1/k!$ since this is  just the                                                   coefficient of the   term $r^{k+1}$.

Comment: But don't we need to remove it since $1/k!$ would turn the polynomial into a rational expression?

Comment: @RobertHönig: No. Here we consider a polynomial in the variable $r$ and $1/k!$ is a constant as for instance in $\frac{1}{6}r(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)$ with $k=3$. In the second case $n$ is the variable which occurs in both numerator and denominator, whereas $k$ is there also considered as constant.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much!

Comment: @RobertHönig: You're welcome.